# struct confusion

Tags: c, function, compiler-construction, struct, scanf

I want to make a function which takes the title and the author of a book and returns 0 or 1 if it is available or not, by comparing them with  a given array of structs.....
Compiler shows:

```
structs.c:10:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘title’
structs.c: In function ‘main’:
structs.c:59:21: error: expected expression before ‘bookRecord’
structs.c:60:13: error: expected expression before ‘bookRecord’
structs.c:61:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘requestBook’
structs.c:61:23: error: expected expression before ‘bookRecord’
```

Here is the code :

```
  #include<stdio.h>           
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>


 #define TRUE 1
 #define FALSE 0

 #define NUM_BOOKS 5

 int requestBook(bookRecord title[],bookRecord author[]){    /* compiler error :10*/
          int i;
          for(i=0;i<=NUMBOOKS;i++){
                  if(strcmp(stacks[i].tittle ,bookRecord.title[0]) == 0 &&                                                                              
                  strcmp(stacks[i].author     ,bookRecord.author[0]) == 0 ){

                  return 1;
                   }
           }
                   return 0;
  }

         typedef struct {
        int minute; 
        int hour;   
         } timeT;


    typedef struct {

       char title[50];  
       char author[50];     
       int year;        
       int isOut;                   
       timeT time;      
       int isBlank;         
  } bookRecord;


  /* given array of struct */

    bookRecord stacks[NUM_BOOKS]=
       {
       {"C How To Program", "Deitel", 2006, FALSE, {0,  0}, TRUE} ,
       {"The Old Capital", "Yasunari Kawabata", 1996, FALSE, { 0, 0}, TRUE},
       {"", "", 0, FALSE, {0,0}, FALSE},
       {"", "", 0, FALSE, {0,0}, FALSE},
       {"", "", 0, FALSE, {0,0}, FALSE}
       };

 int main (int argc, char*argv[]) { 
    int t;

    scanf("%s ",bookRecord.title[0]);         /* compiler error :59*/
    scanf("%s",bookRecord.author[0]);     /* compiler error :60*/

     t=requestBook(bookRecord.title[0], bookRecord.author[0]);   /* compiler error :61
     printf("%d",t);


     return 0;
 }
```

Any help appreciated !

////////////////////////////////////////////////

IF YOU WANT TO SEE THE FINAL SOLUTION PLEASE VISIT  STRUCT CONFUSION(2) IT IS DUPLICATE

////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: no,it was at the final exam !

Comment: @rain... Indeed, homework means non professional. :), and this is !

Comment: @ Jean-Rémy Revy : Yes you are right it is homework !!

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with you code.

1. You declare the structures *after* you use them in the `requestBook` function.
2. In the `requestBook` function you reference the, so far, undeclared variable `stacks`.
3. In the `requestBook` function you use the *type* `bookRecord` as a variable.

There are probably more, but that was what I could find in my first reading.

**Edit:**

A couple of other problems:

1. In the `requestBook` function you loop *one time to many*. Remember that array indexes are from zero to (number_of_entries - 1).
2. You use the type `bookRecord` as a variable in `main` as well.
3. When you erroneously use `bookRecord` you do not get a structure or a string, you get only the first character in the strings `title` and `author`.

Comment: why bookRecord is a variable ....i cant understand that...

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem on this line:

> if(strcmp(stacks[i].tittle ,bookRecord.title[0]) == 0 &&
>                    strcmp(stacks[i].author     ,bookRecord.author[0]) == 0 )

you've misspelled 'title' in the first strcmp function.

Comment: no i fixed that and the problem stays, compiler shows the same ...thanks anyway