# struct confusion (2)

Tags: c, arrays, function, compiler-construction, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [struct confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020275/struct-confusion)

I need help...there is  some  errors in my code ( i have put some comments to the lines ) such like this:

error: EXPECTED EXPRESSION BEFORE ‘bookRecord’

.....This is a programm who stores some book data in an array of structs and uses a function to see if the books users search for  are available or not ..

So I want to fix the errors and make bookRecord not look like a variable,

Do you know how can I do that ,because I am stack here for hours!

Thanks in advance!

```
  #include<stdio.h>           
   #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>


 #define TRUE 1
  #define FALSE 0

 #define NUM_BOOKS 5



     typedef struct {
    int minute; 
    int hour;   
     } timeT;


typedef struct {

   char title[50];  
   char author[50];     
   int year;        
   int isOut;                   
   timeT time;      
   int isBlank;         
 } bookRecord;


/* given array of struct */

  bookRecord stacks[NUM_BOOKS]=
   {
   {"C How To Program", "Deitel", 2006, FALSE, {0,  0}, TRUE} ,
   {"The Old Capital", "Yasunari Kawabata", 1996, FALSE, { 0, 0}, TRUE},
   {"", "", 0, FALSE, {0,0}, FALSE},
   {"", "", 0, FALSE, {0,0}, FALSE},
   {"", "", 0, FALSE, {0,0}, FALSE}
   };


  int requestBook(bookRecord title[],bookRecord author[]){    /* compiler error */
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<=NUMBOOKS-1;i++){
              if(strcmp(stacks[i].tittle ,bookRecord.title[0]) == 0 &&                                                                              
              strcmp(stacks[i].author     ,bookRecord.author[0]) == 0 ){

              return 1;
               }
       }
               return 0;
  }

int main (int argc, char*argv[]) { 
int t;

scanf("%s ",bookRecord.title);         /* compiler error */
scanf("%s",bookRecord.author);     /* compiler error */

 t=requestBook(bookRecord.title, bookRecord.author);   /* compiler error*/
 printf("%d",t);


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this question different than your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020275/struct-confusion)? Please edit the other question or use comments to refine the answers.

Comment: the other questio is also mine... I have changed the code now,the only thing that i am woried about is that I cant understand why bookRecord in those error lines is wrong...Is there any rule or something I dont know in c and the compiler isnt ok ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are using a type instead of variable!

```
bookRecord is a type not variable

int requestBook(bookRecord title[],bookRecord author[]){    /* compiler error */
```

Use this instead (to avoid confusion):

```
int requestBook(bookRecord title_record[],bookRecord author_record[]){
```

Here `title_record` and `author_record` are array of structs of type bookRecord i'm not sure this behavior is what you want you should create a type for author.

For errors inside `main` use the var `stacks` instead of the type `bookRecord`.

Comment: Thanks   a lot!! Despite many warnings it worked ...Your idea was very helpful (for the function part)..I couldn't have made it without your help ! thanks :)